# Multi level for loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a table sidebar which contains the following [image: This table contains 4 distinct entries in sidebar_category]

i want to create an Accordian in bootstrap whose title is fetched from sidebar_category and the body part contains all the sidebar_title with the similar sidebar_category to that on the accodian title. I want to make accordian of all the distinct sidebar_category values.

How can this be achieved using foreach loop, as i'm using Codeigniter.
I want the code to go like:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  //sidebar_Category Should go here
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
              <h5><a href="#">//Sidebar_title should go here</a></h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo" class="active">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                 //Sidebar_category should go here
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <h5><a href="#">//Sidebar_Title Goes Here</a></h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

I could try this:
1) Either use this distinct SQL Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `sidebar_category` FROM `sidebar`
```

that will give me distinct sidebar_category values from the table. Lets assume it to be 4. This could be used for outer for loop iteration to display the categories at the accordian title. The other query would simply fetch the whole table. The problem i'm facing here is how will i identify that run another loop for the next sidebar_category

Comment: Have you tried writing any PHP code so far? If so, post it. If not, try until you get stuck and then ask about something more specific.

Comment: Actually i dont know how to fetch data from DB. Should i use 

SELECT DISTINCT `sidebar_category` FROM `sidebar`

to fetch the distinct values and then use it as a for loop, or should i fetch all the values from the DB and then apply a logic on it

Comment: Ah. Please clarify that you want help with the SQL query in the question by editing it, and perhaps add a SQL tag. Also, if all you want is help with the SQL query perhaps you should remove the twitter-bootstrap and codeigniter tags?

Comment: actually i need help with the logic

Comment: @Anders: edited the question.

Comment: @cyberrspiritt please include your `CREATE TABLE` statements. Images are *not* an acceptable substitute.

Comment: table is already made, how to get the `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of thinking, i've made a logic that suits my need perfectly. The data gets spreaded in the accordian properly. But the accordian panels are not collapsed by default. I'm making a new question for that. Heres the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32557357/2303664)

```
 <?php 
            $fistForLoopEnds = false;
            $secondForLoopEnds = false;
            $thirdForLoopEnds = false;
            $fourthForLoopEnds = false;
             ?>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
           <?php foreach ($this->data2['distinct'] as $key) { ?>

          <div class="panel panel-<?php if ($fistForLoopEnds != true) {
              echo "danger";
              $panelId = "headingOne";
              $accodianId = "collapseOne";
              $accordionExpanded = "true";
          } elseif ($fistForLoopEnds == true && $secondForLoopEnds != true) {
              echo "warning";
              $panelId = "headingTwo";
              $accodianId = "collapseTwo";
              $accordionExpanded = "false\" class=\"collapsed";
          } elseif ($fistForLoopEnds == true && $secondForLoopEnds == true && $thirdForLoopEnds != true) {
              echo "info";
              $panelId = "headingThree";
              $accodianId = "collapseThree";
              $accordionExpanded = "false\" class=\"collapsed";
          } else { echo "success";
              $panelId = "headingFour";
              $accodianId = "collapseFour"; 
              $accordionExpanded = "false\" class=\"collapsed";
              }?>">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="<?php echo $panelId; ?>">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $accodianId; ?>" aria-expanded="<?php echo $accordionExpanded; ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo $accodianId; ?>">
                  <?php echo $key->sidebar_category; ?>
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="<?php echo $accodianId; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="<?php echo $panelId; ?>">
              <div class="panel-body">
            <?php 
                if ($fistForLoopEnds != true) {
                    foreach ($this->data2['results_railways'] as $key) { ?>
                        <h5><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/railways/<?php echo $key->post_id; ?>"><?php echo $key->sidebar_title; ?></a></h5>
                    <?php }
                    $fistForLoopEnds = true;
                    goto a;
                } 
                elseif ($secondForLoopEnds != true) {
                    foreach ($this->data2['results_ssc'] as $key) { ?>
                         <h5><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/ssc/<?php echo $key->post_id; ?>"><?php echo $key->sidebar_title; ?></a></h5>
                     <?php  }
                    $secondForLoopEnds = true;
                    goto a;
                }
                elseif ($thirdForLoopEnds != true) {
                    foreach ($this->data2['results_banks'] as $key) { ?>
                         <h5><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/banks/<?php echo $key->post_id; ?>"><?php echo $key->sidebar_title; ?></a></h5>
                     <?php  }
                    $thirdForLoopEnds = true;
                    goto a;
                }
                elseif ($fourthForLoopEnds != true) {
                    foreach ($this->data2['results_upsc'] as $key) { ?>
                         <h5><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/upsc/<?php echo $key->post_id; ?>"><?php echo $key->sidebar_title; ?></a></h5>
                     <?php  }
                    $fourthForLoopEnds = true;
                    goto a;
                }
                a:
             ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           <?php } ?>
          </div>
```